# Find the minimum number in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I had gone through many articles over internet to  find minimum number in an array. According to article they iterate an array n number of times but purpose can be achieve n/2 + 1 iteration

Here is my code

```
for index in range(0, int(len(myArray)/2)+1):
 if minNum > myArray[index]:
    minNum = myArray[index]

 lastElement = - index - 1

 if minNum > myArray[lastElement]:
    minNum = myArray[lastElement]
```

Article code

```
for element in myArray:
  if minNum > element:
    minNum = element
```

Update my code to

```
for index in range(0, int(len(myArray)/2)+1):
 if minNum > myArray[index]:
    minNum = myArray[index]

 if minNum > myArray[- index - 1]:
    minNum = myArray[- index - 1]
```

Is there is any reason why they used n iteration

Comment: Both variants perform the same number of comparisons.

Comment: @AlexP but number of iteration is less

Comment: Your code is also iterating over all the elements. The only difference is that you iterate half of the array from the end to the middle.

Comment: @VidorVistrom it working correctly i tried on my local for given array

Comment: @Guy If i m not wrong iterating half decrease complexity

Comment: @rahul I meant you iterate the second half of the array with `lastElement` logic, the loop iterates the first half.

Comment: It is the exact same complexity because you perform the exact same number of operations. A decent optimizing compiler should be able to go automatically from the second variant to the first variant by loop unrolling it it considers that it would speed up execution.

Comment: @rahul aah! My bad. I missed to see the indentations. You are however performing n comparisons which I failed to see because of indentations

Comment: Each number that is not the minimum number must be compared to at least one other number. So we must have at least `n - 1` comparisons. I do not see how there can be any speedup.

Comment: That's why algorithms are dealt in Big-O. Small optimizations like these wouldn't change anything in the bigger picture.

Comment: Since you're splitting for half iteration and expecting it to work 2X faster, why not split it into 1/3 iteration, or split 1/4 ...Or Split 1/n times.. you see where I'm getting right. If you split 1/n times you still need to perform n operations. The total number of operations are going to remain the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a small overhead and is actually slower than the article code.

I have made a small program that compares the execution time for both

Check [this](http://tpcg.io/cIpBBM).

Explanation:

In the legacy style,

The loop runs for n times and make 1 comparison every time. Thus abruptly speaking, it takes, O(n) time.
In your code the loop runs for around n/2 times and makes 2 comparisons every time plus the overhead of initializing the

`lastElement`

Thus although both take around O(n) times but the solution OP provides should run slower in most cases

OP's answer could run faster in the case when the degree of sorting is high. Processing sorted arrays is much faster.

Comment: Thanks all for review and reply. If edit above code and instead of initialize lastElement variable, direclty pass "- index -1" in array like this "if minNum > myArray[- index - 1]:
minNum = myArray[- index - 1]" then time complexity is less for my code then article code. Have a look and share your view

Comment: From your own page, after executing the code multiple times, many solutions showed negative result:
The original comparison: 0.11443901062
OP's execution time was faster: 0.117331027985

OP's time is faster by: -0.0028920173645

Comment: @VineethChitteti thats why I said MOST cases. It depends upon how sorted our array is. Looping through a sorted array is much faster in terms of branching. Of course looping through a complete sorted array and a half looping through a sorted array, the latter wins. This is just one scenerio where the OP's result wins and hence I used MOST

Comment: Thanks guys for the great discussion

Comment: @VidorVistrom makes sense. (Thumbs_up). Can you highlight 'most' in the post, so I can upvote :). Cheers. thanks.

Comment: @VineethChitteti the most reasonable case I can think of where OP's answer is faster is the sorted case. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) out. So the degree of sorting plays a major role

Comment: @VidorVistrom, true. I have downvoted this answer first after I read. My bad. Now I can't upvote it unless you edit something in the answer. Can you please make an edit., so I can upvote :)

Comment: @VineethChitteti sure :)